# Not able logout and do a non interactive login with Azure power shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have opened powershell and logged in to azure account by interactive login. Then i want to do a non-interactive login and i have the code for that. PFB is my code.

**But when i use the below code, it is still taking the user from cache and also it is not throwing any error even if i give the wrong password also.**

```
$subscriptionId="Subscription id here"
$tenantid="tenant id here"
$clientid="clinent id here" #appid
$password="password" #i have given the wrong password here
$securePassword = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $securePassword
#Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $tenantid -Subscription $subscriptionId
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential -TenantId $tenantID -ServicePrincipal -Subscription $subscriptionId
```

Here i want to logout from the Azure power shell and use non interactive login with the Service principal(Azure App). Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To log out the account, you could use this command [`Remove-AzureRmAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/remove-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-4.4.1) , or close the powershell and open a new one.

To use non interactive login with the Service principal, you could use the command below, the password is the secret of your AD app.

```
$azureAplicationId ="Azure AD Application Id"
$azureTenantId= "Your Tenant Id"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal
```

[image]